# Whitelist webbrowser control c#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, whitelist

In my webBrowswer control on my Windows form, I only want 2 URLS to load, otherwise, I want to page to stop loading if it tries to go to any other pages. WinForms.

```
 private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = !e.Url.Host.StartsWith("http://9.9.9.9/system.xml");
        e.Cancel = !e.Url.Host.StartsWith("http://9.9.9.9/top.xml");
    }
```

The above still loads pages that aren't what is specified....any ideas?

Comment: the logic isnt good. the second if overrides the result of the first one

Comment: How would you recommend I approach it?

Comment: if(!url.startwith(x) && !url.startwith(y)) e.Cancel = true; Have you verified that e.Cancel = true does what you want

Comment: It doesn't seem so...is there a better way to achieve my desired result?  
if (!e.Url.Host.StartsWith("http://9.9.9.9/system.xml")   e.Cancel = true; doesn't work either.